# React Native Firebase Firestore onSnapshot queries with orderBy and limit does not return all records instead of one record for the first time

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in my React Native chat app. I am running the following code to get messages for a conversation.  There are more than 10 records (messages) available in Firestore Database and the following query returns only 1 record for the first time. Then it returns 9 other records by running a second cycle even without changing any document in the firebase database. (Refer the attached screenshot for debugging results).

DB Path :- `(collection)conversations / (document)<conversation key> / (collection)messages`

Note: This strange thing only happens when the user clicks on a conversation for the first time. Then this thing won't ever happen until I clear app data.

```
async onMessagesFirestore(key, callback) {
  this.unsubscribeMessage = await Firebase.firestore()
    .collection('conversations')
    .doc(key)
    .collection('messages')
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .limit(10)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      callback(querySnapshot.docChanges())
    })
```

}
[image: Debugging result]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: You can improve the question using the "edit" link at the bottom.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in a simple react app. Could you place a `console.log(querySnapshot.docChanges())` and check if it's content is correct?